# How to automatic deploy spring boot in jenkin and put images to docker

Tags: spring-boot, docker, jenkins

I using jenkins spring boot and docker in my app. I want deploy spring boot in jenkin and put jar when deploy into docker and start it automatic. I reference to here :
https://denisdbell.wordpress.com/2017/08/26/automated-deployment-jenkins-docker-spring-boot/

But i have a problem. It deploy success but don't run jar in docker. When i type docker - ps it show me jar and i must run it manually. I want when jenkin deploy it automatic put images into docker and run it automatic.

I have two question: 
- In my project spring boot, i need put docker in root project ?
-  How to jenkin deploy and put images to docker and run automatic jar when jenkin deploy
-  When i have mutiple modules, how to i specific copy only jar modules i need deploy and copy to docker and run it.

Thanks you so much help me

Answer (score 0):

Question 1:- Yes you need to add it to the root folder.

Question 2:- You have to use the **dockerfile-maven-plugin** to push/pull images and use the shell commands from Jenkins to run the same.

Add the SCM GIT, Stash, Hg as this

```
<scm>
  <connection>scm:git:ssh://git@guthub.com/yourproject.git</connection>
  <developerConnection>scm:git:ssh://git@guthub.com/yourproject.git[push=]scm:git:ssh://git@guthub.com/yourproject.git</developerConnection>
  <tag>HEAD</tag>
</scm>
```

Add the plugin as

```
<plugin>
<groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
<artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.4.3</version>
<executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>build</goal>
                        <goal>push</goal>
                    </goals>
        </execution>
</executions>
<configuration>
    <repository>${docker.image.prefix}/yourproject-${project.artifactId}
    </repository>
    <tag>${project.version}</tag>
</configuration>
```

In this while building your jar pass the arguments
`mvn clean install -DskiptTests -Ddocker.image.prefix=<your docker repo url>`

This command would automatically push the latest project version docker image to the repository.
Use the Shell commands to fetch this image and start the docker from the shell.